# What does the meaning of version setting in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

There is a tab "version setting" when we used to view visualforce page. I never used it. If someone knows how to use this and what is the reason of this tab in visual force ( In case of Apex class i know) ?.

In image below I am seeing two rows for versioning one is "Salesforce API" and  other is "Salesforce for Social media". "Salesforce for Social media" is installed  package but "Salesforce API" in not any package. How this versioning effects on visulaforce page.

[image: version setting tab]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every release salesforce introduces new components and enhancements in visualforce as well as it is with apex triggers and apex classes .

For example consider this new release winter 14 ,there are new components added like apex:input and datalist attributes this will be available only if your version of visualforce is 29.0 and salesforce preserves the backward compatibility with the help of the versions .

So you may upgrade your visualforce page version to new one but with some caution after completing testing in sandbox.

Answer (score 4):

This is the release version of Salesforce. As some releases introduce new or changed functionality you can version specify your visual force page.

For instance to safeguard your custom build functionality which may have dependencies on platform functionality salesforce chooses to alter or deprecate.